# php error insert data with value including addition sign (+) to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There is an error while i insert "3 + 1 room" or update description area with "3 + 1 room" in MySQL database.

I saw there is no addition sign "+" in MySQL log (data inserted in database)

```
UPDATE testtable set status='0',title='3   1 room',
description='3 1 Daire. 1 Balkon kapalı.' WHERE id='60';

create table testtable ( id int(11), status tinyint(4), title varchar(20), 
description text) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

php file

```
$baglanti=new PDO("mysql:host="localhost";dbname="test";charset=utf8",$us
ername,$passwd) or die("error");
$val=$baglanti->exec("UPDATE testtable set status='0',title='$title',
    description='$dest' WHERE ad_no='$ad_no' ");
return $val;
```

What should I do?

**EDIT**

update.php

```
<?php
        include("database.php");

        $fields = array();
        $values=array();
        $fvalue=$_POST['id'];

        $table=$_POST['table'];
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

                if( $key!='table' && $key!='id' && $key!='alan'){
                        if( strpos($key,"date")){
                                $datet=new DateTime($value);
                                $value=$datet->format('Y-m-d');
                        }
                        array_push($fields,$key);
                        array_push($values,$value);
                }
        }
        $alan=$_POST['alan'];

$ID=Updt($table,$fields,$values,$alan,$fvalue);

        if($ID!=0){

                echo $ID;
        }
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php 
     $baglanti=new PDO("mysql:host="localhost";dbname="test";charset=utf8",$us
ername,$passwd) or die("error"); 
#UPDATE
function Updt($table,$set,$value,$field,$fvalue){
        $bag=$GLOBALS['baglanti'];
        $sts='';
        if(is_array($set)){
                for ($i=0; $i < count($set); $i++) {
                        $sts.=$set[$i]."='".$value[$i]."',";
                }
                $sts=rtrim($sts,",");
        }else{
                $sts=$set."='".$value."'";
        }
        $val=$bag->exec("UPDATE $table set $sts WHERE $field='$fvalue'");

        return $val;
}

?>
```

this one, programmers wrote code. I try to take question parts from all code. There were lots of codes in file.

Comment: Where do all these variables come from??

Comment: Does your `pdo new......` really have a line break in the middle of the `$username` variable?

Comment: Do you see the message `error` on the screen or in the mysql error log

Comment: @naf4me - since when was `+` considered a "special char"?

Comment: Actually your connection string is a complete mess, you must be seeing `error` either on the screen or in the `mysql error log`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can'T see any error log in mysql. and I see only "3 1 room" in mysql.log.. I can manually add `Update ..... set description = "3 + 1 room" succesfully.

Comment: replace your connection code with this `$baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8", $username, $passwd) or die("error");`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I can succesfully connect database in PHP file.

Comment: Then you are not showing use the real code. Show us the real code

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I can update  `UPDATE testtable set status='0',title='$title',
    description='3 - 1' WHERE ad_no='$ad_no'` in php code.

Comment: Is there any rule in PDO about special characters? I'm not programmer. database administrator .

Comment: Show us HOW you create `$title` and `$dest` and `$ad_no`

Comment: As @MarkBaker said earlier `+` and `-` in a text/varchar column **are not special characters** They are just like any A-z 0-9 etc If you dont trust me truct him, he knows what he is talking about

Comment: I edited. I can update using mysql command line with "+" .  but In php part, it can't

Comment: @Álvaro González Not really very helpful towards a solution

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's alright, I'll retract the close as dupe. But every time I read "special characters" and "SQL" in the same question there's someone injecting raw input into SQL code. Almost every char is special when you treat data as code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks I have attempted to put him on course for solving his own issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not generating the query you think you are.

This should allow you to see the query.

I have also added some error checking, that really should be used in this code.

I have amended the connection line as I am sure a newline in the middle of the `$username` variable will cause an error.

database.php

```
<?php 
    try {
        $baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8",
                             $username,$passwd);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

#UPDATE
function Updt($table,$set,$value,$field,$fvalue){
    $bag = $GLOBALS['baglanti'];
    $sts='';
    if(is_array($set)){
        for ($i=0; $i < count($set); $i++) {
            $sts.=$set[$i]."='".$value[$i]."',";
        }
        $sts=rtrim($sts,",");
    }else{
        $sts=$set."='".$value."'";
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE $table set $sts WHERE $field='$fvalue'";
    echo $sql;      // you can comment this line out when you are sure the SQL is good

    $val = $bag->exec($sql);

    return $val;
}
?>
```

update.php

Small amendment here just so you know whats actually being returned from the function is a count and not a row ID. It could also be FALSE, indicating an error occured in the `Updt()` function in the query.

```
<?php
    include("database.php");

    $fields = array();
    $values=array();
    $fvalue=$_POST['id'];

    $table=$_POST['table'];
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if( $key!='table' && $key!='id' && $key!='alan'){
                    if( strpos($key,"date")){
                            $datet=new DateTime($value);
                            $value=$datet->format('Y-m-d');
                    }
                    array_push($fields,$key);
                    array_push($values,$value);
            }
    }
    $alan=$_POST['alan'];

    //$ID=Updt($table,$fields,$values,$alan,$fvalue);
    // this is not an ID it is a coumt of the number or rows
    // updated by the Updt() function

    $cnt = Updt($table,$fields,$values,$alan,$fvalue);

    if ( $cnt === FALSE ) {
        // then we had an error in Updt()
        print_r($baglanti->errorInfo(), true);
        exit;
    }

    if($cnt != 0){
        echo 'Rows updated = ' . $cnt;
    }
?>
```

> I have to mention this as others will if I dont. Your code is open to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) you should really be using prepared statements. Maybe you should mention this to the Programmers you mentioned. Maybe you should also not assume everything they wrote was done correctly.